# Multiply 2 sparse matrices using cusp library

Tags: cuda, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, cusp-library

Im new to using cusp library for cuda. I'm trying to implement revised simplex algorithm for CUDA. For that I need to multiply 2 sparse matrices to update the base matrix.

So the question is - how can I multiply 2 sparse matrices(doesn't really matter in what format) using cusp library? Also is there a way to know how many nonzero elements is the result matrix going to contain(for memory allocation purposes)?

I tried:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cusparse.h"
#include <cusp/version.h>
#include <cusp/multiply.h>
#include <cusp/array2d.h>
#include <cusp/print.h>
#include <cusp/coo_matrix.h>

int main(void)
{
    cusp::coo_matrix<int,double,cusp::device_memory> A(2,2,2);

    A.values[0] = 1;
    A.row_indices[0] = 0;
    A.column_indices[0]= 0;

    A.values[1] = 1;
    A.row_indices[1] = 1;
    A.column_indices[1]= 1;

    cusp::coo_matrix<int, double, cusp::device_memory> B(2,2,4);

    B.values[0] = 1;
    B.row_indices[0] = 0;
    B.column_indices[0]= 0;

    B.values[1] = 2;
    B.row_indices[1] = 0;
    B.column_indices[1]= 1;

    B.values[2] = 3;
    B.row_indices[2] = 1;
    B.column_indices[2]= 0;

    B.values[3] = 4;
    B.row_indices[3] = 1;
    B.column_indices[3]= 1;

    cusp::print(A);
    cusp::print(B);

    cusp::coo_matrix<int,double, cusp::device_memory> C(2,2,4);

    cusp::multiply(A,B,C);

    cusp::print(C);

}
```

As cusp:multiply() was the only function for multiplication I found.

cusp v.0.4
CUDA v.5.5

Comment: Is there a problem?  Your code seems to run fine for me.  I don't think you need to know the size of the result matrix.  Change your definition of the C matrix to: `cusp::coo_matrix<int,double, cusp::device_memory> C;` and your code still works.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I multiply 2 sparse matrices(doesn't really matter in what format) using cusp library?

Yes, `cusp::multiply` is the correct function for this.  Your code works correctly for me.

> Also is there a way to know how many nonzero elements is the result matrix going to contain(for memory allocation purposes)?

You don't need to allocate it ahead of time.  Change your definition of the `C` matrix to this:

```
cusp::coo_matrix<int,double, cusp::device_memory> C;
```

and your code still works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. This code didnt work for me, but I found the problem. For some reason when I had compute capability set to 3.5 and SM version also to 3.5 it wasnt working. I set it to 2.0/2.1 and its working just fine now.

Comment: Those compile settings need to match the GPU you are actually running on.

Comment: And what should I do when the final code will be runinng on GTX Titan with 3.5/3.5 and Im writing it at home on gtx 570 (2.0/2.1) ?

Comment: Compile for both.  Use [nvcc extended notation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#extended-notation)